# Rearrange SASS IntellIJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sass

I need to write SASS code in a strict arrangement order (e.g. z-index before display before background...). IntelliJ offers [custom](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-code-style-scss.html#ws_scss_settings_editor_code_style_arrangement) CSS and SCSS arrangements. Is this also possible for SASS or is there any plugin or cli that ships a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code rearrangement is currently only supported for CSS and SCSS; if you miss SASS support, please file a feature request to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB